# In 2.93 what is the background node called for adding an environmental background

Tags: lighting, world, shader-nodes

Following a tutorial done in 2.78 on the anvil, The next step was to add a ref background. The environmental node went through a math node to background node but I don't know what to connect it to in 2.93.[image: Node set up]Could you please tell me where I have gone wrong this my best attempt, but no picture, behind anvil and no world lighting in viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the left center of your screen where it says "Object" and change it to "World". You will then have access to to the World Shader options (Including the Background Node). Make sure you are in Rendered Preview Mode in order to be able to see your image and have its lighting influence your scene. Or, if you want to stay in Material Preview mode, enable "Scene Lights" and "Scene World" from the Viewport Shading options menu (arrow next to the preview mode circles - top right):

[image: World2]

Comment: Just found the video being referenced - he connects the Image Color Output to the _Background Input_ and the Output of the Math Node to the _Strength Input_.

Answer (score 0):

World shader, and cycles are the keys.

This is what I have, with it wired as shown in the picture, but you may want something different.  [image]:

environment> math multiply>background strength> mix shader> world output